# When should we add not null constraint when defining a domain?

Tags: grails

Many times i find myself in a dilemma when designing a new domain class. When i create a new domain class in Grails i have few properties. I can either add not null constraints on these properties or make them nullable. This choice seems optional in many cases in the domains i create. So, what are some of the good reasons to add not nullable constraints and also not blank constraint. I need few points to understand when should one care about these constraints. Thanks!

```
static constraints = {

        title nullable:true, blank:true

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be thinking about your models...  Take a Widget.  What attributes are **necessary** to constitute a Widget? Perhaps it's just a name, or a part number, and all other attributes are nice-to-have's or extra details. Maybe its a name AND part number. Necessary attributes would receive the nullable:false. Any others could be nullable:true.

blank, true or false? Well, I don't see much utility in a blank string as a value. I'd rather deal with a simpler case or null versus not null to indicate if there is data present.

Comment: Thanks! That aids my understanding.

Comment: thinking of a widget analogy, let's take an alarm clock. For this widget i would assume not nullable properties could be weight, color, water resistent, digital etc and nullable  property could be owner. Is that right?

Comment: It gets back to a modeling question. Weight, color, etc depends on what is necessary, or nice-to-have, or irrelevant to your system. If you're modeling physical reality, then all the attributes you mention nullable:false (and possibly many more) might be correct, including the owner as nullable:true. If your system has a simpler definition of an alarm clock, then those nullable flags may change.

Answer (score 1):

`nullable` means, that the attribute there may be devoid of value.  This is also how (SQL) databases model that - so this setting will end up in your table constraints with your (SQL) database (e.g. `NOT NULL`).

Also (SQL) databases can query for that: `is null` and `is not null`.  This might lead to some surprising results (e.g. with order).

Being `nullable` makes e.g. an Boolean tri-state.  It can be `true`, `false`, or `null` - so /yes/, /no/, or /no decision made/ (or revoked).

When modelling your DB with GORM a common place for `nullable` is for 0..1 associations.

Or in short: think of `Optional` or `Maybe`.

Comment: so booleans should normally be not nullable. is that correct?

Comment: I'd not say that.  E.g. if you add a new flag in your system (feature on/off) you can leave it nullable, to signal "no one has yet decided for or against that feature". Even if there is no value, it holds an information.

Answer (score 1):

Scenarios where,

we add `constraint` :- `nullable :false, blank:false`

- property is means of `identity`
- property is adding `value(importance)`
- property is going to help in `reducing query complexity`
- property can not be `null` or `blank` just because of business logic.